# Open website in kik from other browsers

Tags: kik

I want  to send the users of my website (that already have kik installed) to see the website in the Kik browser.

I know that 
kik://users/username/profile
will direct to the user profile in the kik app.

Is there something similar, but for websites not profiles?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://mywebsite.com/` -> `card://mywebsite.com/`

`https://mywebsite.com/` -> `cards://mywebsite.com/`

Comment: what does this mean? this answer needs to have more depth. Explain why you gave these answers

Comment: works like a charm! thx!

@CodeGodie that is how the URI should look like if you want to redirect the mobile users to the kik app

Comment: @jairajs89 what about sending a message? do you know how we can do that using url schemes?